# Using docker-compose push to push container to registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The problem: I have a contenirized node.js app that uses mongodb using `docker-compose.yml`. Now I need to push it to my registry. How do I do this?

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  node_app_1:
    container_name: node_app_1
    restart: always
    build: .
    image: myusername/node_app_1
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
    networks:
      app_net:

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:3.6.6-jessie
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      app_net:
        aliases:
          - mongo

networks:
  app_net:
```

When I run `docker-compose push` the image is pushed to the repo, but when I pull it and run I get an error, saying that my node.js app cannot connect to mongo. Also environment variables are not set as well.

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose push` only pushes the *images* to the registry, not the compose file itself (see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/)). To set up the full application again, pulling from the registry, you'd need another compose file without the `build` statement, and use `docker-compose up`.